# Unable to Backup to Network Share Using Standard Backup Methods in SSMS BUT Works using Ola Hallengren's Scripts - SQL 2019

Tags: sql-server, backup, permissions, sql-server-2019

We have recently installed our first instance of SQL 2019 and are having a weird issue with trying to backup to a network share using the standard methods found in SSMS but it's working fine with Ola's scripts. When trying to right click on a database and back it up, or when trying to create a maintenance plan to back up the database I get the following error once it tries to validate the network share that we use for backups on this instance:

```
The operating system returned the error 0x80070005(Access is denied.) while attempting 'SvlPathDoesPathExist' on '\\SCBACKUP01\SQLBackups\SCMBAPP\DEFAULT'
The statement has been terminated. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3634)
```

I have verified that the service account that is running both our SQL Server and the SQL Agent (we use the same for both) has FULL access to the network share. We set up all of our instances the same way and none of our 2012 and 2016 instances have an issue.

I tried a second instance of SQL 2019 and the same issue, it won't work if you right click and backup or try to use a maintenance plan but it works perfectly when using Ola's scripts.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you backing up to the exact same directory regardless of backup method? Have you tried using T-SQL to issue a `BACKUP DATABASE` command to help zero in on the difference in methods?

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be either the maintenance plan, or Ola's script is set to "Run as" an account other than the SQL Agent account in the job. Proxy account might not have adequate permissions.

Comment: @MikePetri The SQL Jobs that have Ola's scripts in them have nothing in the 'Run As' dropdown for each of the job steps so I am guessing it's using the SQLAgent Service Account to run those jobs, same as the maintenance plan.

Comment: @AMtwo Yes, I am backing up to the same directory regardless of the method. Also, I just tried issuing a ```BACKUP DATABASE``` command and it worked perfectly, no errors.

Comment: Hook up a trace and see exactly which command is failing. A backup command is fine, you say, so it might be ssms doing xp_dirtree, for instance.

Comment: It looks like your account have issues with permissions on the target UNC.
When you run backup database command, SQL server does it under its own service account.

Comment: @AndreySamykin, I don't think that is the issue. The maintenance plan also runs under SQL Server's own service account and that is one of the parts that is not working. Are you also saying that if I right click and choose to back up the database that it is using my personal account, I don't think that is correct. Remember, SQL Server Service account and SQL Agent are both running under the same account.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, I have never done that level of troubleshooting yet. Any resources you can point me to to help guide me there?

Comment: @TattooedDBA "When trying to right click on a database and back it up, or when trying to create a maintenance plan to back up the database I get the following error" - here you work with GUI under your own credential;  "just tried issuing a BACKUP DATABASE command and it worked perfectly, no errors" - here you ran backup database command w/o backup db wizard (I guess) and it worked fine (SQL server did it under its account).

Comment: @AndreySamykin, doing it through the GUI doesn't mean that you use your own credentials. the GUI will submit SQL commands to SQL Server so that SQL Server try to access the resource. What is more likely that the GUI issues some SQL command that causes this to fail, something that isn't involved in a simple BACKUP command. Hence me requesting a trace.

Comment: @TattooedDBA Check out https://sqlblog.karaszi.com/ssms-17-3-has-built-in-profiler/ and https://sqlblog.karaszi.com/tips-for-getting-started-with-extended-events/ , that should hopefully get you started.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, indeed, my bad.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi, thanks for the links. I will work on this and report back.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi - quick question. Will Extended Events or SQL Profiler even catch the error? I am getting this error when trying to set up a maintenance plan, at the step where it tries to verify the backup location. Here is an image of the error at that step: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rsibnbzmcrh44cw/MaintenancePlanError.jpg?dl=0

Comment: You can catch the error, yes. It is all about what events you are capturing. This smells like an issue that MS should fix, considering it worked in prior versions. However, having more information when reporting it to MS isn't a bad things. Note that you also want to catch the ...starting event (like sqlbatch_started or whatever the exact name is), not only the completed event, since this commands fails, hence you won't get a completed event.